# Use different ViewModel for ASP.NET MVC 3 global error page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using a global filter to handle errors in ASP.NET MVC 3 (with Razor views).  However, my shared/_Layout view requires a view model which I've called PageViewModel.

When I hit an error the shared/Error view gets compiled - however because it is referencing the layout file I'm getting this exception:

> Exception message: The model item passed into the dictionary is of
>   type 'System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo', but this dictionary requires a
>   model item of type 'ViewModels.PageViewModel'.

Any idea of how to solve this?

Here's the error view:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h2>Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
```

Comment: Are you using the HandleErrorInfo model in the Error view?

Comment: No, the entire view is posted above.

Comment: If you are not using any values from the HandleErrorInfo, does the error view need to be strongly typed? Alternatively, does the layout need to be strongly typed? Won't this cause the same problem for any other strongly type views?

Comment: The strongly typed layout is required so I can drop site settings etc into the standard template. I suppose I could do this differently by using child actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just put the error into the ViewBag, and just send the view the normal PageViewModel?

Here is good example of global exception handling in MVC, [How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: I'm not specifically calling the view - that's happening from within ASP.NET somewhere - do you know how to override this so I can change the view model that gets sent?

Comment: Here is good example of global exception handling in MVC, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc. You should probably going down this path to specifically call your error view. I am with Dallas though that having a strongly typed layout is probably going to give you other issues down the line.